# Ignore lambda argument checking

Tags: ruby, lambda, proc

I want to convert a proc that exhibits lambda behavior (argument checking) into one that doesn't. The following is a very contrived example, but it should get the point across:

The aim is to create a DSL that looks something like this:

```
NumberSeries.perform do
  add first_series:  -> { natural_numbers.take(10) },
      second_series: -> { fibonacci_numbers.take(10) }
end
```

Note that `natural_numbers` and `fibonacci_numbers` are not passed as arguments in the DSL. The implementation of `add` looks something like this:

```
NaturalNumbersFibonacciNumbers = Struct.new(:natural_numbers, :fibonacci_numbers)
FAMOUS_NUMBER_SERIES = NaturalNumbersFibonacciNumbers.
                         new(natural_numbers, fibonacci_numbers)

def add(first_series:, second_series:)
  first_numbers  = FAMOUS_NUMBER_SERIES.instance_eval(&first_series)
  second_numbers = FAMOUS_NUMBER_SERIES.instance_eval(&second_series)
  first_numbers.zip(second_numbers).map { |x, y| x + y }
end
```

Now, if I replace `->` with `proc` in the DSL, it will work. However, keeping the lambdas, I would get

> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

as [`BasicObject#instance_eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval) yields self to the lambda, but the lambda expects no arguments.

---

I don't want to use [`Fiddle`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/fiddle/rdoc/Fiddle.html) for obvious reasons.

Comment: Does `instance_exec` work instead – that allows you to pass arguments (or not in this case)?

Comment: I'm confused. Why not just define your DSL with procs? `add first_series: proc { natural_numbers.take(10) }` is just as elegant.

Comment: @matt, yep, `instance_exec` did the trick. No idea how I haven't thought of that. Even though it doesn't answer the question, it solves the original problem so add that as an answer and if noone knows how to do it, I will accept it.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - for a Rubist - yes. In general - no.

Comment: For this particular task: `&->(*args) { λ.call }`. For general `lambda` one might examine `λ.parameters` and build the respective `proc` wrapper. The only question is: why on the Earth anybody would need that?

Comment: @mudasobwa, wrapping it another proc that calls the original lambda wont work as it wont be `instance_eval`ed (the context will be different and you would get undefined variable or method `natural_numbers`). As for the why part - to create a very specifically looking DSL.

Comment: “In general—no” I do not see any reason of using `lambda` where `proc` should be used, then convert `lambda` to `proc` because of bad design and claim that using `proc` is “less elegant.”

Comment: @mudasobwa, don't think of it as *"you shouldn't do that in Ruby"* and more like *"I want to implement a language and it just so happens that I can implement it as a Ruby internal DSL rather than create a parser"*.

Comment: `first_series:  ->(*) { natural_numbers.take(10) }` then.

Comment: @mudasobwa, that requires a change in the language interface.

Comment: No it does not. You probably answered before I fixed a mistake there (`*` instead of `_`.)

Comment: @mudasobwa, it still does. People have to use `->(*)` instead of `->`.

Comment: The docs say that the only operation that doesn't preserve lambdaness is `define_method`, which adds it, so you may be out of luck

Comment: @FrederickCheung, using `instance_exec` does solve the original problem. However, it would still be nice if you give [Quotation].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`instance_exec`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_exec) is an alternative to `instance_eval` that allows you to control the parameters passed to the block, and doesn’t pass the receiver as `instance_eval` does. You can use it as a workaround to your problem as it allows you to pass zero args:

```
irb:108:0>  Object.new.instance_eval &-> { puts "Hello" }
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
    from (irb):108:in `block in irb_binding'
    from (irb):108:in `instance_eval'
    from (irb):108
    from /Users/matt/.rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
irb:109:0>  Object.new.instance_exec &-> { puts "Hello" }
Hello
=> nil
```